# How to make my app show up in the list of browsers when I click on any link in Android?

Tags: android

```
    <intent-filter> 
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:scheme="appname"/> 
</intent-filter>
```

I tried that but still my app won't show up in the list of browsers when I click on any link. What might be going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried including `android:mimeType="text/html"` (for example) in the `<data />` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this filter:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: how cordova app can get given URL?